# Google Sheets - Data importing

Tags: google-sheets

I was wondering if someone could help with this scenario:

On Google Sheets, I am looking to take data from Sheet 2 and place it in Sheet 1 (Master list), so the data in sheet 2 is temporary and has 5 cells to manually enter data, I want to create a button that submits this data from sheet 1 to sheet 2 and at the same time enters a new row in sheet 2 and clears the data entered in sheet 1.

thanks

Comment: Hi. Which particular aspect of this do you need help with?

Comment: It might help for you to re-read [How do I ask a good question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) - the scenario that you have described is pretty common, but the details of your situation are vague, and lacks clarity about the data layout, data fields, what you are trying to achieve. Would you summarise the research that you did before positing this question, and then edit your question to provide more information, and perhaps some before/after screenshots

Comment: Hi @tedinoz, thanks for asking for a better question from me, I had done some research (didnt save the links) then I have come across this article which has essentially got what I want to do for now: https://www.bpwebs.com/how-to-create-a-data-entry-form-in-google-sheet/

Comment: Well, that's positive. The author of that article says _"... this method is better for mass data entry [] than Google Forms"_ and I'm not sure that I would agree with that. But this will obviously get you going. You might also consider playing with Google Forms to see how the two compare.